# Slow data structures in multiprocessing Python library

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing

I am trying to make simple computations for large data structures with multiprocessing library. It is something that I need for my thesis, so please don't be stern for me.

When I decided to divide my computations for multiple "workers", "threads", "processes" or call it as you want, I started looking into python docs to find what I need and I found two modules, 'threading' and 'multiprocessing'. After reading, I decided to use 'multiprocessing' cause it looks like something I need.

The problem is that with multiple workers (processes) my computations are much slower. First thought was related to size of my input data. I understand that for small data, 'cost' of running threads is much bigger than simple computation, but for larger structures efficiency should growth.

I was really supriced that my computation (for example 2D Rosenbrock) is few times faster for iterative algorithm than with computation made with few processes. And computation is done for 100k tuples.

I also noticed that multiprocessing.Queue access is few times slower than access to collections.deque, but I really need to have this computation is some kind of "shared memory" or something similar.

Can someone explain me where is the problem? Is it Python so much efficient that it's not worth to compute it with multi processes? Do I use proper data structures? Can I change something in my perception of multiprocessing? Or maybe even I measure it in bad way? I really appreciate for any clue how I can speed it up.

Full code below

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import multiprocessing
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import random
import collections

class Worker(multiprocessing.Process):
    counter = 0
    def __init__(self, idx, from_queue):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.from_queue = from_queue
        self.idx = idx

    def run(self):
        print ("Worker started", self.idx)
        for data in iter(self.from_queue.pop, None):
            x_1, x_2 = data
            result = 100*(x_2-x_1**2)**2 + (1-x_1)**2

def main():
    tuple_counts = 100000
    min_x = -5
    max_x = 5

    tuples = multiprocessing.Queue()
    for _ in range(tuple_counts):
        my_tuple = {random.uniform(min_x, max_x), random.uniform(min_x, max_x)}
    tuples.put(my_tuple)

    cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1

    pops = []
    for _ in range(cores):
        pop = collections.deque()
        pops.append(pop)

    for pop in pops:
        for _ in range(int(tuple_counts/cores)):
            pop.append(tuples.get())


    for _ in range(int(tuple_counts % cores)):
        pops[_].append(tuples.get())

    for pop in pops:
        pop.append(None)

    workers = []
    process_time = 0
    process_time_start = timer()
    for i in range(multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1):
        worker = Worker(i, pops[i])
        workers.append(worker)
        worker.start()
    for worker in workers:
        worker.join()
    process_time_stop = timer()
    process_time += (process_time_stop-process_time_start)
    print("process_time", process_time)

    iter_time = 0
    iter_timer_start = timer()
    for _ in range(tuples.qsize()):
        x_1, x_2 = tuples.qet()
        result = 100*(x_2-x_1**2)**2 + (1-x_1)**2
    iter_timer_stop = timer()
    iter_time += (iter_timer_stop-iter_timer_start)
    print("iter_time", iter_time)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Passing data around is usually something you want to avoid. What prevents you from just telling each worker how many tuples to process and letting them independently generate and process the random tuples?

Comment: Im not sure if I understand it. How can I tell each worker that he needs to compute lets say 100 rosenbrocks? Of course I can pass it as argument or you mean something else? When I was using one queue for every worker, I think it was even slower.

Comment: The queue needs to serialize and deserialize all the tuples that you create in order to pass them around from your parent process into the child process. The serialization and deserialization probably takes more time than simply calculating the result. In general, it's best to avoid passing data around like that. Just pass to the worker a single integer telling it how many tuples to generate and do it all within the worker.

Comment: Ok looks better. What if I need data later? Next step has to be done on this calculated data in few processes too so I need to pass this calculations to other processes which will cause serialization too I think

Comment: You would try and avoid doing that. Since your data seems to be independent, can you not just perform the computations in the same `Worker` objects and avoid moving it around?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing arguments across process boundaries to do a simple calculation.  I expect it will be extremely slow.

If you need speed, I recommend you fall back to a single threaded implementation, and find a way to vectorize it using numpy. Profile it with cProfile. Attack the hot spots.

A huge benefit of numpy is reduced python overhead (name resolution, looping, etc).

Once you've got the single-threaded approach fast, only then move on to parallel processing.

An added benefit of vectorizing your problem is that numpy unlocks the GIL for lengthy calls, allowing true threading, vs multiprocessing.

Comment: How can I pass this tuples in much efficient way instead? Thanks for other adivices but it looks like something more to read

Comment: @Tatarinho: I'd suggest you seriously look into numpy. Even with an optimal `multiprocessing` setup, you will not be experiencing any appreciable gains in speed. For comparison, vectorized processing of 1,000,000 items with my naive numpy approach takes 9.3ms and a list comprehension takes 1.53s. Multiprocessing can only reduce that 1.53s by a factor of maybe 3 or 4.